# How to put a square bracket in an HTML list?

Tags: html

I would like to put square brackets, a semicolon and parenthesis in an HTML list:

```html
<li>Carrie "...always miss[es] the ball, even in kickball, fall[s] on her face in Modern Dance... run[s] into the net during volleyball; wear[s] stockings that always run... always show[s] sweat stains under the arms of her blouses" (9).</li>
```

Will this break any HTML parsers?  Do I need to escape them, and if so, how?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have any issues here.

Answer (score 0):

No. Square brackets, parentheses and a semicolon will not affect how the document is parsed.

Angle brackets (`<` and `>`) and ampersands (`&`) have to be given as HTML entities (`&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;`, respectively).